# How can I get all parents' parents as columns for child object in circularly referenced table?

Tags: sql, circular-reference

I have a table with columns like

```
entityID, entityName, parentID
```

How can I write a query to return all the levels of parents for an entity as to return something like

```
childentityname, parentlevel1name, parentlevel2name, parentLevel3name and so on
```

I am not a SQL ninja by any means. Is this possible? If so, how?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server DB.

Comment: I also have this question :p  Try not to make the answer specific to this DB though.  Postgres here.  I have a work-around solution that will get it for X number of levels.  But it doesn't expand infinitely only for a specific number of times.  Let me know if you want to see that solution, but it's not pretty.

Comment: id love to see it... they want this application to be dynamic in that you can add hierarchy levels but the reports are kickin my butt... luckily the table also has a level ID so i can use a bunch of case statements to get the reports lookin how they should, but once these levels change, then down goes my reports... just a couple luckily

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the app written in?  And one sec while I pull up the query.

Comment: Wait a sec...my answer below will give you a table of parents. What you want to do is essentially pivot the parents out into columns? That is a horse of a different color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive CTE is what you need [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) (EDIT: Only in SQL SERVER 2005+)

Something along the lines of:

```
WITH recurse_cte (entityID,entityName, parentID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.entityID,e.entityName, e.parentID,
        0 AS Level
    FROM self_joined AS e
        UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.entityID,e.entityName, e.parentID,
        Level + 1
     FROM self_joined AS e
    INNER JOIN recurse_cte AS cte
        ON e.entityID = cte.parentID
)

select * from recurse_cte
```

Comment: this little chunk of code just bailed my a$$ out on a project.  thank you sooooooo much NullRef!  very nice!

Answer (score 0):

On postgres, this is exactly what `WITH RECURSIVE` is for. You probably don't need to do much more than change column names from the ([linked here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)) documentation.

I don't know if the OP's DB supports recursive, probably depends on version number. If available, the syntax will be similar or identical. If not, it's a big nuisance. It's very hard to make a pure SQL solution, especially if the number of levels is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  'accounts'.'id' AS id_0,
  'accounts'.'child_id' AS child_id_0, 
  'child_accounts_1'.'id' AS id_1, 
  'child_accounts_1'.'child_id' AS child_id_1, 
  'child_accounts_2'.'id' AS id_2, 
  'child_accounts_2'.'child_id' AS child_id_2, 
  'child_accounts_3'.'id' AS id_3, 
  'child_accounts_3'.'child_id' AS child_id_3, 
  'child_accounts_4'.'id' AS id_4, 
  'child_accounts_4'.'child_id' AS child_id_4
FROM 
  'accounts' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 'accounts' 'child_accounts_1'
  ON 'child_accounts_1'.'id' = 'accounts'.'child_id'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 'accounts' 'child_accounts_2'
  ON 'child_accounts_2'.'id' = 'child_accounts_1'.'child_id'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 'accounts' 'child_accounts_3'
  ON 'child_accounts_3'.'id' = 'child_accounts_2'.'child_id'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 'accounts' 'child_accounts_4'
  ON 'child_accounts_4'.'id' = 'child_accounts_3'.'child_id'
WHERE 'accounts'.'id' = 56
```

This is very similar to what you're doing except mine is a hierarchy of children.

The `accounts` table has an attribute `negative_overflow_account_id` which references itself.  This here will grab the 'id' and 'negative_overflow_id' of the first 5 layers of the nesting.

I wrote in my code a loop that will generate this query based on the constant MAX_OVERFLOW which will generate this when set to '5', and will do more/less if a different number is used.

Basically my use-case was to make sure someone wasn't setting an infinitely circular loop, so if it hits level 5 then an error goes to the user telling them they can't set it that deep.  And if any of the levels references the top-level or one of the previous levels then an error is also generated indicating circular recursion  (Which would crash the app later down the line if allowed to persist).

EDIT:  I shortened the names.  noone wants to see my stupid ridiculous naming convention for that dumb table ;)

Comment: With the advent of RECURSIVE, this is really not the best approach. Can you imagine what a mess this becomes 20 levels deep? NullRef's example will also work in Postgres.

Comment: Oh I'm aware this approach gets really bad as the levels get deeper.  I'd like to see an example using RECURSIVE though I'm not sure I 100% sure I followed those docs (Guess I'd have to look at them closer).  Looks like a good place to refactor my own code :p